# Problema con la generación de librerías en Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, angular9

Estoy migrando un proyecto a Angular 9 desde Angular 7. Mi proyecto se compone de una librería que exporta módulos o paquetes por separado, formando parte de la ruta relativa. Esto es:

```
@my-library // main library

@my-library/my-module // module of my library
```

Esto se consigue dejando el `ng-package` en la raíz de la librería, y creando en cada módulo un `package.json` que apunte a su propio `public_api`. Por último el `public_api` de la raíz exporta todos los módulos utilizando la notación `@my-library/my-module`

Hasta aquí todo correcto, en Angular 7 compila bien.

Tras migrar a angular 9, y añadir la librería `ng-packagr: 9.1.1`, y actualizar las demás librerías, las de angular a la 9.1.1, el devkit de angular a 0.901.1, Typescript a la 3.8.3 y tsickle a la 0.38.1. Existen problemas con la tarea de build.

El problema llega cuando un módulo de la librería tiene dependencia con otro, y el compilador de Typescript no es capaz de reconocer los ficheros raíz de ese módulo.

[image: Error typescript]

En angular 7 como digo funciona correctamente, los módulos tienen sus rutas relativas en `imports` y `exports` en `public_api`, y cuando se agrega una dependencia se usa la notación `@my-lib/my-module`.

Parece ser que el compilador de `typescript 3.6` en adelante, tiene un comportamiento o hace unas comprobaciones distintas a lo esperado.

Estas son mis dependencias:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.1",
    "base64-arraybuffer": "^0.1.5",
    "creditcards": "^3.1.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.8.5",
    "iban": "^0.0.11",
    "rxjs": "6.5.4",
    "text-mask-addons": "^3.8.0",
    "text-mask-core": "^5.1.2",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.901.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.1",
    "@types/iban": "0.0.30",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.5",
    "ng-packagr": "^9.1.1",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "replace-in-file": "^3.4.2",
    "tsickle": "~0.38.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
```

Este es mi tsconfig de la raiz

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@ambar/ng": [
        "projects/main/public_api"
      ],
      "@ambar/ng/project": [
        "projects/main/project/public_api"
      ],
      "@ambar/ng/config": [
        "projects/main/config/public_api"
      ],
      "@ambar/ng/crypto": [
        "projects/main/crypto/public_api"
      ],
      "@ambar/ng/emulation": [
        "projects/main/emulation/public_api"
      ],
      "@ambar/ng/error": [
        "projects/main/error/public_api"
      ],
      "@ambar/ng/forms": [
        "projects/main/forms/public_api"
      ],
      "@ambar/ng/http": [
        "projects/main/http/public_api"
      ],
      "@ambar/ng/i18n": [
        "projects/main/i18n/public_api"
      ],
      "@ambar/ng/logger": [
        "projects/main/logger/public_api"
      ],
      "@ambar/ng/storage": [
        "projects/main/storage/public_api"
      ]
    }
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

Este es mi tsconfig.lib de la libreria:

```
 {
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/lib",
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "types": [],
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2018"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "annotateForClosureCompiler": true,
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
    "strictMetadataEmit": true,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "enableResourceInlining": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Este es mi angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "demo": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "test/cli/demo",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "aot": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "demo:build",
            "proxyConfig": "proxies/local.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "demo:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "demo:build",
            "i18nFormat": "xlf",
            "i18nLocale": "en-GB"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "main": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "projects/main",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/main",
      "prefix": "lib",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr:build",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "projects/main/tsconfig.lib.json",
            "project": "projects/main/ng-package.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "tsConfig": "projects/main/tsconfig.lib.prod.json"
            }
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "projects/main/test.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/main/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "projects/main/karma.conf.js"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "watch": false,
              "codeCoverage": true,
              "browsers": "ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox",
              "reporters": [
                "mocha"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "projects/main/tsconfig.lib.json",
              "projects/main/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "main"
}
```

Comparto también el scaffolding de mi libreria

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿A alguien más le ha pasado?

Actualización:

He conseguido aislar y reproducir el problema en un proyecto nuevo, os comparto un repositorio clonable en el que podéis reproducir los problemas.

La issue explicada de manera genérica: [Problemas en el Build de libreria angular 9 cuando existen dependencias entre modulos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/352130/problemas-en-el-build-de-libreria-angular-9-cuando-existen-dependencias-entre-mo)

Repositorio para reproducir el error:

https://github.com/Noeldesarrollo/angular9-lib-build-issue

Muchas gracias.

Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Primero migraste a angular 8 y después a 9? ¿De frente fuiste a Angular 9 desde Angular 7?

Comment: Migré directo de angular 7 a angular 9. Entiendo que en la manera de generar y empacar las librerias no han habido grandes cambios desde angular 6. Lo único que he visto es que el empacador lo han externalizado a la libreria ng-packagr. Y en cuanto al builder del devkit de angular, ha dejado de ser extensible, para sólo poder usar ciertas funciones que exponen, pero esto es más de puertas hacia adentro.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar tu `tsconfig.json` por favor?

Comment: Agrega también el `angular.json` por favor :D y recuerda hacer el recorrido: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Ya lo he actualizado, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes tu proyecto guardado en GIT, debes volver a su versión con angular 7 para actualizarlo en angular 8 y luego a 9.

Puedes seguir la [guía oficial de angular](https://update.angular.io/#7.0:9.0) y tengas en cuenta algunos puntos importantes:

Para actualizar a angular 8:

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
```

[Aqui hay una guia para actualizar **angular 8 a 9**](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/upgrade-to-angular-9-within-10-minutes-671c6fd6174b):

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a lo que veo, parece que te hace falta unos detalles en el `angular.json`

He duplicado las mismas 2 líneas en 2 áreas diferentes, prueba y espero que ya se solucione el problema.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "demo": {
      "root": "projects/demo", //Aqui te falta especificar lo mencionado, le pondré projects/demo
      "sourceRoot": "projects/demo/src", //Aqui cambiaré src por projects/demo/src
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "projects/demo", //Aqui te falta especificar lo mencionado, le pondré projects/demo
      "sourceRoot": "projects/demo/src", //Aqui cambiaré src por projects/demo/src
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "test/cli/demo",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "aot": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "demo:build",
            "proxyConfig": "proxies/local.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "demo:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "demo:build",
            "i18nFormat": "xlf",
            "i18nLocale": "en-GB"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "main": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "projects/main",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/main",
      "prefix": "lib",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr:build",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "projects/main/tsconfig.lib.json",
            "project": "projects/main/ng-package.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "tsConfig": "projects/main/tsconfig.lib.prod.json"
            }
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "projects/main/test.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/main/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "projects/main/karma.conf.js"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "watch": false,
              "codeCoverage": true,
              "browsers": "ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox",
              "reporters": [
                "mocha"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "projects/main/tsconfig.lib.json",
              "projects/main/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "main"
}
```

Comment: desgraciadamente lo que no compila es la librería, la aplicación demo si compila bien

Comment: `"sourceRoot": "projects/main"` -> `"sourceRoot": "projects/main/src"`

Comment: Buenas, he compartido el scaffolding de mi librería. Como se puede ver el root y sourceroot coinciden, no hay src, son todo modulos que se exportan independientemente aunque compilan todos bajo la misma librería, esto en angular 7 me ha funcionado, no se si han habido cambios al respecto.

Answer (score 0):

Ya está resuelto.

El package.json de la librería tenía el nombre mal puesto, por tanto intentaba compilar la librería raiz, y los demás módulos como dependencias suya, por eso daba error.

Al cambiar el nombre, y poner el path base del que parten los demás módulos. Ahora cada módulo compila independientemente y no hay problemas.

Por tanto en el public_api global, los export de los módulo @my-workspace/mylib/mymodule coinciden con el nombre del package.json de la raiz de la librería que ahora tiene por nombre @my-workspace/mylib